# How to adjust bxslider vertical alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I am using bxslider to create a simple slideshow on my homepage.  I am hosting the bxslider.min.js and the bxslider.css locally.  Everything works fine, except that my images are not centered vertically - there is a white band at the top and the captions are cut off at the bottom (an example is [here](http://automaticrelease.org/index%20bx%20slider%20test.html)).

From reading other posts, I tried adding the following to the CSS - (it was not a category originally):

```
.bxslider-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none !important;
}
```

I have also tried changing everything labelled "margin" or "padding" in the CSS to 0 but nothing has worked (I know the CSS is connected, as I am able to change other parameters).

Under the script I have:

mode: 'horizontal',

```
    speed: '5000',
    captions: true,
    pagerCustom: '#bx-pager',
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    slideWidth: 1000,
    slideMargin:0,
    auto: true,
    autoControls: false,
```

I am not the most advanced at HTML/CSS/JS - so I am probably overlooking something obvious.  I have been at it for days and it's making me crazy so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have a margin for your ul.bxslider

Try adding

```
.bxslider { 
 margin: 0;
}
```